# R: find if number is within range in a character string

Tags: regex, r, string, strsplit

I have a string `s` where "substrings" are divided by a pipe. Substrings might or might not contain numbers. And I have a test character string `n` that contains a number and might or might not contain letters. See example below. Note that spacing can be any

I'm trying to drop all substrings where `n` is not in a range or is not an exact match. I understand that I need to split by `-`, convert to numbers, and compare low/high to `n` converted to numeric. Here's my starting point, but then I got stuck with getting the final good string out of `unl_new`.

```
s = "liquid & bar soap 1.0 - 2.0oz | bar 2- 5.0 oz | liquid soap 1-2oz | dish 1.5oz"
n = "1.5oz"

unl = unlist(strsplit(s,"\\|"))

unl_new = (strsplit(unl,"-"))
unl_new = unlist(gsub("[a-zA-Z]","",unl_new))
```

Desired output:

```
"liquid & bar soap 1.0 - 2.0oz | liquid soap 1-2oz | dish 1.5oz"
```

Am I completely on the wrong path? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an option using r-base ;

```
## extract the n numeric
nn <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9|. ]", "", n))
## keep only numeric and -( for interval)
## and split by |
## for each interval test the condition to create a boolean vector
contains_n <- sapply(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9|. |-]", "", s),'[|]')[[1]],
       function(x){
         yy <- strsplit(x, "-")[[1]]
         yy <- as.numeric(yy[nzchar(yy)])
         ## the condition
         (length(yy)==1 && yy==nn) || length(yy)==2 && nn >= yy[1] && nn <= yy[2]
       })

## split again and use the boolean factor to remove the parts 
## that don't respect the condition
## paste the result using collapse to get a single character again
paste(strsplit(s,'[|]')[[1]][contains_n],collapse='')

## [1] "liquid & bar soap 1.0 - 2.0oz  liquid soap 1-2oz  dish 1.5oz"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it is general enough, but you might try:

```
require(stringr)
splitted<-strsplit(s,"\\|")[[1]]
ranges<-lapply(strsplit(
          str_extract(splitted,"[0-9\\.]+(\\s*-\\s*[0-9\\.]+|)"),"\\s*-\\s*"),
          as.numeric)
tomatch<-as.numeric(str_extract(n,"[0-9\\.]+"))
paste(splitted[
            vapply(ranges, function(x) (length(x)==1 && x==tomatch) || (length(x)==2 && findInterval(tomatch,x)==1),TRUE)],
             collapse="|")
#[1] "liquid & bar soap 1.0 - 2.0oz | liquid soap 1-2oz | dish 1.5oz"
```

Comment: if `n=2.3oz`, the output still includes `dish 1.5oz`

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method starting from your `unl` step using `stringr`:

```
unl = unlist(strsplit(s,"\\|"))
n2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]*", "", n))
num_lst <- str_extract_all(unl, "\\d\\.?\\d*")
indx <- lapply(num_lst, function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 1) {isTRUE(all.equal(n2, as.numeric(x))) 
  } else {n2 >= as.numeric(x[1]) & n2 <= as.numeric(x[2])}})

paste(unl[unlist(indx)], collapse=" | ")
[1] "liquid & bar soap 1.0 - 2.0oz  |  liquid soap 1-2oz  |  dish 1.5oz"
```

I also tested it with other amounts like `"2.3oz"`. With `n2` we coerce `n` to numeric for comparison. The variable `num_lst` isolates the numbers from the character string.

With `indx` we apply our comparisions over the string numbers. if there is one number we check if it equals `n2`. I chose not to use the basic `==` operator to avoid any rounding issues. Instead `isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))` is used.

Finally, the logical index variable `indx` is used to subset the character string to extract the matches and paste them together with a pipe `"|"`.

Comment: In which package does `lengths()` exist? Cannot find it in `help`

Comment: It is a base function in R 3.2.0

Comment: It can be replaced with `unlist(lapply(num_lst, length)) == 1`

Comment: Works for `1.5oz`, produces `NA|NA|NA|NA` for `2.3oz`

Comment: Updated with `isTRUE`

Comment: Thanks! Works now. Cannot accept more than 1 answer. Upvoted tho